# Calling jquery methods on dynamically added elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, button

We can make all elements of class 'button' as JQuery UI Buttons using the following

```
$('.button').button();
```

But what if we also wanted any future elements added to also be UI Buttons.

How can we achieve that?

Comment: What event is triggering the buttons to be added?

Comment: The dom is being modified by a third party api that is outside our control. So looking for a general method that didn't require any knowledge of how the modification was occurring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you'll have to explicitly call the method after the element is added.

e.g If you are adding a button to the div with id `xyz` then

`$("#xyz").append(" <button>").button();`

I'm still searching for a better solution , and would post **if** I find one

Comment: I don't have control over adding the buttons, so need to be able detect when something is added.

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding them at a well-defined spot, then you can just do something like:

```
var newButton = $("<input>", { type: "button" });
$("body").append(newButton);
newButton.button();
```

Or you can use the [LiveQuery plugin](http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs) (as suggested by JohnP) and listen for DOM addition events:

```
$(".button").livequery(function() { $(this).button(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use  livequery to reinitialize your plugin calls : http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs

Answer (score -1):

What you might want to use is the `delegate` method. You can find more about it here: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

```
$('yourSelector').yourHandler();
```

becomes

```
$('yourSelector').delegate('yourHandler');
```

Comment: Delegate is for triggering event handlers only. It doesn't work as you described.

Comment: `delegate` attaches a `handler` , you cannot call methods with it